# How to detect if the time is between 2 set times (Google Apps Script)

Tags: date, datetime, google-apps-script

So, I'm making a program, where when a specific function is called, it checks the current time, and executes an action depending on the time. 
Currently, inside my function, here is my code:

```
var d = new Date();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var timeSplit = currentTime.split(':');
  var timeH = timeSplit[0];
  var timeM = timeSplit[1];
  var timePM = timeSplit[2].split(' ')[1]
  if (timeH >= 9 && timeM >= 30 && timePM == 'AM') {
    function1()
  } else if (timeH == 10 && timeM >= 25 && timeM < 30 && timePM == 'AM') {
    function2()
  } else if (timeH >= 10 && timeM <= 30 && timePM == 'AM') {
   function3()
  } else if (timeH >= 11 && timeM >= 40 && timePM == 'AM') {
    function4()
  }
```

You kinda get the point

It doesn't return any errors, but it also doesn't execute any functions either. How can I fix this?

Comment: From what I can see, depending on the time, none of the four conditions will be met (for example, if `timeH` is below 9). Have you checked if that's the case?

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your script, `timePM` might be `undefined`. By this, no functions in the if statement are not run.

So how about this modification?

### Pattern 1:

#### From:

```
var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

#### To:

```
var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
```

### Pattern 2:

#### From:

```
var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
var timeSplit = currentTime.split(':');
var timeH = timeSplit[0];
var timeM = timeSplit[1];
var timePM = timeSplit[2].split(' ')[1]
```

#### To:

```
var h = d.getHours();
var timeH = h < 12 ? h : h - 12;
var timeM = d.getMinutes();
var timePM = d.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
```

#### Reference:

- [toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)